# replace several matches of a substring with their indexes

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

assuming that you have a string with multiple occurrences of the same substring what would be the best one-liner to replace the matches with their another substring which contains the index of the math as well? As an example, let's say you have the following string: `This is a test.` and we want to replace all the occurrences of `is` with `X` and their index to have something like: `ThX-0 X-1 a test.`

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
echo 'This is a test.' | perl -pe 's/is/"X-" . $c++/ge'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, runs the code on it and outputs the processed line.
- `s///g` runs a substitution globally, i.e. on all the positions where it's possible
- `/e` interprets the replacement part as code and runs it. The code here uses the concatenation operator `.` on the string `X-` and the value of `$c`, increasing it by one at the same time.

Comment: and what if you want it to be case insensitive?

Comment: Just add the `/i` modifier, i.e. `/gei`.

Comment: thank you, it works. It works fine. But, how you restrict the scope of the counter to the lines? I mean what if you want the index to start from 0 in each line?

Comment: @amin: Then prefix the substitution with `$c=0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution in `awk` will be:

```
awk '{while(sub(/[iI][Ss]/,"X-"count++)){a=""};count=""} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per anubhava sir's comment adding above code's shorter version:

```
awk '{while(sub(/[iI][Ss]/,"X-"count++));count=""} 1'  Input_file
```

Simple explanation will be, run a loop till a substitution is found and do literally nothing inside it :) print the line at last.

Comment: This may be shorter: `awk '{while(sub(/[iI][Ss]/,"X-"count++));} 1'`

Comment: @anubhava, Sure thank you sir added this version now, cheers.

Comment: thank you guys. It works. But, how you restrict the scope of the counter to the line? I mean what if you want the index to start from 0 in each line?

Comment: @amin, Sure done the changes now, these will start over the count of X- from 0 in each line onward, lemme know in case of any queries here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative gnu-awk one liner:

```
echo 'This is a test.' | awk -v RS='[iI][sS]' '{ORS = "X-" i++} 1'
```

```
ThX-0 X-1 a test.
```

To reset counter for each line:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' 'This is a test.' 'This is another this' |
awk -v RS='[iI][sS]' '/\n/{i=0} {ORS = "X-" i++} 1'
```

```
ThX-0 X-1 a test.
ThX-0 X-1 another thX-2
```